# Wordpress custom field select box search "at least" value

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I have two custom post types, `ads` and  `bedrooms`.

I have made a custom search form with a select box like so:

```
<select name="bedrooms" id="bedrooms>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1 bed+</option>
    <option value="2">2 beds+</option>
    <option value="3">3 beds+</option>
</select>
```

How can I link it so that when a user searches for `2 beds+` it will show all ads with 2 bedrooms or more?

Comment: Can you post your php code for the search? And, specifically, what is the field name that contains the number of beds?

Comment: hi gibberish, the field name is called "cp_bedrooms" ,ill post the code this evening when i get home, the strange thing is if i put <select name="cp_bedrooms"> it will search all ads with the specific number of bedrooms selected, im using classipress theme if that makes a difference, cheers

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to extract the (minimum) number of beds the user has selected. To do that, you need a bit of javascript (or [jQuery, which is what I recommend](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2013/05/06/why-javascript-is-doomed/)).

Here is code that watches for the select element's value to change. Probably you won't use that *event*, but the code shows you how to read the control's value (and how to properly use the `selected` attribute):

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Hd8h/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<select name="bedrooms" id="bedrooms">
    <option value="0" selected>Choose One:</option>
    <option value="1">1 bed+</option>
    <option value="2">2 beds+</option>
    <option value="3">3 beds+</option>
</select>
<div id="resultsDiv"></div>
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
$('#bedrooms').change(function() {
    var beds = $(this).val();
    alert('Minimum beds: ' + beds);
});
```

Once you have the (minimum) number of beds saved into a variable, you can use AJAX to send a request to the server to perform a search and return the results:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "somephpfilename.php",
    data: 'num_beds=' + beds,
    success: function(recd){
        $('#resultsDiv').html(recd);
    }
});
```

The above will send the contents of the variable `beds` over to the PHP side, re-naming it `num_beds`. I changed the var name so that you can see how the names match up. On the PHP side, retrieve the number of beds as: `$_POST['num_beds']`

You can then do a mysql search and construct some HTML code inside a variable. When done, just echo out that variable. (Note that I am using `$out .= "more stuff";` to append to the variable contents, and then `echo` the variable when finished.

PHP: **somephpfilename.php**

```
$min_beds = $_POST['num_beds'];
$query = "SELECT * IN `yourtablename` WHERE `cp_bedrooms` > '$min_beds' ORDER BY `cp_bedrooms`";
$results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$out = '
    <table id="foundApts">
        <tr>
            <th>Num Beds</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Contact Phone</th>
            <th>Rent</th>
        </tr>
    ';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results){
    $out .= '
        <tr>
            <td>' .$row['cp_bedrooms']. '</td>
            <td>' .$row['address_field_name']. '</td>
            <td>' .$row['phonenum_field_name']. '</td>
            <td>' .$row['rentprice_field_name']. '</td>
        </tr>
    ';
}

$out .= '</table>';

echo $out;
```

What is echoed out by PHP (that is, the contents of the `$out` variable -- the HTML constructed on the PHP side) is received inside the AJAX `success:` function in a variable called `recd`. Just write that variable into the results div and you will see the fully constructed table of results. **Note that you must do this *inside* the `success:` function. You will find that the `recd` variable does not exist outside this function.**

Here is a non-working link to a jsFiddle with everything put together. Note that it is non-working because jsFiddles cannot do AJAX and there is no place to put the PHP *(I just added the PHP inside a comment, but it should be saved into a file on the PHP file system).* Just observe how the code is constructed.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Code Sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Hd8h/1/)</kbd>

---

Here are some additional notes regarding AJAX/PHP:

[How to use jQuery in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859708/ajax-jquery-doubts/18860002#18860002) (you only need to include the jQuery library, as shown in `One:`)

[Simple intro to AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843)